# Whenever I run this function from its script it doesn't work correctly, but when I move it to main it works just fine. Why is this happening?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that gives an approximation of pi based off of a recursive algorithm. When I wrote the function in main it worked perfectly, but when I moved it back to its own script it kept giving back a false answer. What am I doing wrong?

This is the function in its own script "liuhui.py"

```
import math


def pi_LiuHui(epsilon):
    M = 1
    error = 1
    sides = 6.0
    aN = 2.59808

    while error > epsilon and error < 20:
        m = math.sqrt(((M / 2) ** 2) + (1 - math.sqrt(1 - ((M ** 2) / 4))) ** 2)
        sides = sides * 2.0
        apoth = math.sqrt(1 - (m / 2) ** 2)
        aTri = (m * apoth) / 2
        a2N = aTri * sides
        error = a2N - aN
        aN = a2N
        M = m

    return a2N
```

This is the function call in main.py

```
import math

from liuhui import pi_LiuHui

print(pi_LiuHui(0.0001))
```

The output for this is 3.401919999999999. However, this is the function when written in main.py

```
import math

epsilon = 0.0001
M = 1
error = 1
sides = 6.0
aN = 2.59808

while error > epsilon and error < 20:
    m = math.sqrt(((M/2)**2) + (1 - math.sqrt(1 - ((M**2)/4)))**2)
    sides = sides * 2.0
    apoth = math.sqrt(1 - (m/2)**2)
    aTri = (m * apoth)/2
    a2N = aTri * sides
    error = a2N - aN
    aN = a2N
    M = m

print(a2N)
```

This outputs 3.1415838921483186, which is correct. Is there a way to make the function behave this way in the other script?

Comment: It works fine for me.  I get 3.1415838921483186 both ways.

Comment: I tried to run the function in one file and by importing it from a different file and I got the same correct result for both. be sure your variables aren't shadowing some name from the outer scope. this could be the reason. if you have debugger you it and you will easily figure out where the bug is.

Comment: Same here, both results are identical

Comment: I am getting the expected results. This comment does not provide the solution to your problem. Could you give us more information?

Comment: The debugger fixed it, I have no clue how but it works fine both ways now